# Declaring date in SSRS via logic

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

Can anyone let me know how to declare a date in SSRS via some logic?

`if today = Monday` then start `date = today - 3days`

`if today != (not equal to ) Monday` then start `date = today - 1day`

This should be given in SSRS so that if I click today's date, yesterday's data should come in my report.

Comment: thank you , can you please modify the same . if todays date is of Monday then I need the data of Saturday as well as of Friday .report for Monday to Saturday .because I have the data for Saturday also . thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that on Sunday this should also default to Friday, you can set your parameter default to:

```
=IIf(WeekdayName(Weekday(Today)) = "Sunday", DateAdd("d", -2, today), 
 iif(WeekdayName(Weekday(Today)) = "Monday", DateAdd("d", -3, today), 
 DateAdd("d", -1, today)))
```

Or For SQL:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2016-04-18'; -- Monday
SET @Date = DATEADD(DAY, CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 
                            WHEN 1 THEN -2 
                            WHEN 2 THEN -3 
                            ELSE -1 
                        END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Date));

SELECT  @Date;
```

Which gives `2016-04-15` (Friday)

Comment: The OP may not need it for Sunday. We usually do the same thing so that users get reports Mon - Fri with Monday's report including the weekend (Fri - Sun).

Comment: thanks for the answer ,
there is a requirement saying that in a parameter of date there should be only one date entry and the report should be generated from the date of entry till the end date as yesterday .

Comment: thank you , can you please modify the same . if todays date is of Monday then I need the data of Saturday as well as of Friday .report for monday to saturday .because I have the data for Saturday also . 

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write an expression in SSRS to set Date

```
=IIF(Weekday(Today()) = 2,DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-3, Today()),DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-1, Today()))
```